# Scala : reassignment to val

Tags: scala

I am looking for a way to resolve the below compilation error in Scala. I am trying to update the value of a variable `clinSig`, if the `clinSig` is null while calling `method1`.

```
import org.joda.time.Instant 
import java.util.Calendar

class TestingClass {   
    method1(null)   
    private def method1 (clinSig : Instant) {
    if (clinSig == null) {
      val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
      calendar.set(2011, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0)
      calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)
      clinSig = new Instant(calendar.getTime)
    }
    print(clinSig)   
   } 
}
```

---

```
error: reassignment to val
 [INFO]       clinSigUpdtDtTm = new Instant(calendar.getTime)
```

Comment: Well , it is going to make 'clinSig' is never used.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Method parameters are `val`s so you can't re-assign them. You can create a new `val` and assign that based on the condition:

```
val updated = if (clinSig == null) {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.set(2011, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0)
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)
    new Instant(calendar.getTime)
}
else clinSig

println(updated)
```